# Convert a pointZ layer to a point layer

Tags: qgis, shapefile, convert

I have a shapefile that show this description under *Geometry type of the features in this layer*:

```
Point (WKB type: "PointZ")
```

I need to use is it in some plugins that seems to work only with points:

```
Point (WKB type: "Point")
```

I know how to access the `Z` value,  `z($geometry )`, but how can I convert the geometry type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, but not obvious.
When I choose *save as*,  in the new window I have to foce the geometry to point and unclick the *include z-dimension*.

[image]