# Least Cost Path Error

Tags: qgis, cost-path, least-cost

I am working in QGIS and have been wanting to do a simple Least Cost Path Analysis using the SAGA tool. I have created a Slope raster for it, as well as an Accumulated Cost Surface. I have two points which I have imported from Google Earth and transformed into two separate point layers. I have tried numerous times to run the plug in, but I keep getting the same error:

ERROR: The start-point layer contains no legal point.

I tried to re import the points, change the CRS, researching on the internet and watching tutorials, but nothing seem to work or to give a reason for this issue. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286967/convert-a-pointz-layer-to-a-point-layer for how to transform, this article may help

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I realized that the reason was the points were `PointZ`. Just transform them into simple point and it will work.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Please click 'edit' and add detail to your answer - which tools should be used to convert PointZ to Point?

Comment: thanks for the very good tipp, I have just saved the point again, and when saving just take out the mark on save _z value_, and thats all